# Can't find nitrogen package for Alpine Linux

Tags: linux, package-management, alpine-linux

I can't find the "nitrogen" package for Alpine Linux, they changed the name (for example the change of xorg-xinit to just xinit) or there is a better alternative?

I tried to find by the search command and by the packages site and nothing, I really like nitrogen but if there's a better alternative for this distro in particularly I can get than I'm sold.

btw I'm using the Awesome manager.

Comment: What even is Nitrogen? // Not all software is available packaged for every Linux distribution.

Comment: It`s just a wallpaper manager, i was wondering if they just changed the name.